# Unable to hit API after application is hosted on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-web-api

I have created a very basic Web API project. When I run the application from VS and hit a url like http://localhost:57401/users/getmessage I am able to get the response. After I have hosted it on IIS and provided it binding I am unable to hit the same url. I am getting 404 error. The URL I hit is http://testapi.com:6060/users/getmessage and this gives a 404. If I hit http://testapi.com:6060/Default.html I get the page without any error. The 404 error is only for api. Here is the routing attribute I use for the controller method:

```
[Route("users/getmessage/"), HttpGet]
```

and the WebApiConfig.cs is like:

```
 public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.EnableCors();
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.MediaTypeMappings.Add(new RequestHeaderMapping("Accept", "text/html", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase, true, "application/json"));
    }
```

What could be wrong? Where am I making the mistake?

Here is the IIS image.[image: IIS Manager]

Comment: These routing problems are a pain, I admit. Could you try: http://testapi.com:6060/users/users/getmessage

Comment: I hope you API is directly published on the site that is on your server port 6060 i.e. under sites -> <xyz site> (when you expand this you can see bin folder etc.) ? If not can you share the folder structure of your IIS Manager.

Comment: @RyanPeters No. It isn't working as well.

Comment: @RaviA. I can see the bin folder under the application.

Comment: Still it would be great if you can share image of IIS Manager. Apart from that I hope you have installed all the necessary components (Application Development Features), although you won't see a 404 if some installation is missing.You can try enabling FREB (http://www.iis.net/learn/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis) and see if the extension less handler is actually being called.

Comment: @RaviA. I have attached the image.

Comment: that looks good. Have tried enabling FREB ?  Can you try this http://stevemichelotti.com/resolve-404-in-iis-express-for-put-and-delete-verbs/

Answer (score 1):

This recently happened to me and it turned out to be the route template getting in my way.

You've got "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}" as your route template right now.  So when you debug you'll hit it with something like "http://localhost:2342/api/users/getmessage" and it will work.

When you install this in IIS, you used the word "API" as your application name, so on IIS the URL to get to the service is "http://localhost/API".

So to hit the same call when hosted on IIS you would need 
"http://localhost/API/api/users/getmessage".

You can fix it by removing the "api/" from the front of your route template.  Then it will work like you expect.

Answer (score -1):

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
name: "DefaultApi",
routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
```

);

please add the action name in url route config.

Comment: I have made the changes but no effect. The error remains the same. Please check my updated question for complete configuration in WebApiConfig.cs file. Thanks.

Comment: /api/users/getmessage please use this i think you are missing the api route that is way not working.

Comment: config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/v1/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Test1", action = "Get", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

Comment: that is my current setting in api ,so can utilize like that

Comment: and please remove the [Route("users/getmessage/"), HttpGet] from your controller.